# iOS Xcode BLE receiving different data lengths

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am developing an iOS app using BLE, I have the BLE comms working but I do not seem to receive any data. The plan is to use multiple BLE UUID characteristics to send data from our ECU to the iOS mobile app. I know the BLE ECU is working as I have checked it with a BLE scanner.

I have followed this example, but still cannot get the BLE read to work correctly. Oddly if read the bytes back one by one I get the required data, but I cannot seem to find a solution to read the complete string in one go? I could use a loop to read all the data back, but surely there must be a way to read back the BLE receive buffer in one go?

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/ultimate-how-to-bluetooth-swift-with-hardware-in-20-minutes/

Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {

      var characteristicASCIIValue = NSString()

      guard characteristic == rxCharacteristic,

      let characteristicValue = characteristic.value,
      let ASCIIstring = NSString(data: characteristicValue, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) else { return }

      print("Value Recieved: \((characteristicASCIIValue as String))")
    
    if(characteristic.uuid.isEqual(CBUUIDs.ECU_UUID_A)
    {
        print ("Found ECU_UUID_A")
       Extract_ECU_UUID_A(ASCIIstring)
    }
    else if(characteristic.uuid.isEqual(CBUUIDs.ECU_UUID_B)
    {
        print ("Found ECU_UUID_B")
       Extract_ECU_UUID_B(ASCIIstring)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Do you have a single read characteristic (which is typical if you have an emulated serial port) or multiple characteristics? Your code seems to be trying to use both approaches. You check to see if `characteristic == rxCharacteristic` which implies a single characteristic but then you check for two different characteristic identifiers.

Comment: I have multiple characteristics so trigger a mass read and then check the UUID which are been read back with the dUpdate function. So should there be a different call back for multiple charactertics?

Comment: The characteristic whose data is being provided is passed as `characteristic` to the delete function you have shown. That is why I am confused as to why you are checking to see if it is `rxCharacteristic` but then expediting it to be one of two other characteristics. It can't be both at the same time.

Comment: Many thanks, I found another bug in my code which means the receive BLE is not working so it’s trigging the wrong uuid and not getting any data back from our ecu. 

More bug fixing required, many thanks for your help

Comment: @Brendon so do you need more help than what you already posted or this can be considered as closed? BTW, if you're not getting any values, please make sure you're subscribed to that ```characteristic``` else the ```didUpdateValueFor``` won't get triggered I believe.

Comment: I have still not fixed the issue, but working though to find a solution. We can close this out and once I figure out the problem I will provide an update to the ticket